# Run an executable, wait for it to produce output, run another program

Tags: python, subprocess, executable, popen

Within a Python script, I'm trying to execute the following sequence of events:

1. Open a command window and run a program. When it completes, it outputs a text file.
2. Once that text file has been created, close the program.
3. After that has happened, run a new program using the text file as an input

Here's what I have so far:

```
subprocess.popen(['cmd','/c',r'programThatRuns.exe'])
subprocess.wait()  # ? subprocess.check_call()? kill?
subprocess.popen(['cmd','/c',r'otherProgramThatRuns.exe'])
```

So I guess I'm really stuck on the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to apply 'wait' on the child process, i.e.

```
o = subprocess.popen(['cmd','/c',r'programThatRuns.exe'])
o.wait()  
subprocess.popen(['cmd','/c',r'otherProgramThatRuns.exe'])
```

or you use `check_call`

Answer (score 7):

I think all you need is:

```
subprocess.check_call(['programThatRuns.exe'])
subprocess.check_call(['otherProgramThatRuns.exe'])
```

The `check_call` function will run the program and wait for it to finish. If it fails (non-0 exit code) it will throw a `CalledProcessError` exception.

You generally don't want to run programs through `cmd`, just run them directly. You only need to force using cmd if the program isn't an executable, e.g. for a builtin command like `dir`, for a `.bat` or `.cmd` file, or if you want to use file associations.

Comment: Thanks. A wrinkle that I didn't state well is that programThatRuns.exe outputs the text file, but then stays open, causing .check_call() to hang

One alternative is to query to see if the text file has been created, then issue a kill for programThatRuns once it has. But I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `subprocess.call`?

[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) - [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the returncode attribute.

Seems to be what you're trying to do. Simply run the first process, check that the file exists, and pass the file into the second process to use.

`subprocess.check_call` will also work for what you're trying to do, except that if the process returns a non-zero return code it'll raise an exception while `call` will simply return the return code.

Comment: Since OP is opening up the text file as input immediately afterwards, you'd definitely want the exception to raise